# Deployment Results - What do the Line and Column refer to?

Tags: deployment, logging

I am trying to deploy an application from a sandbox to production. Validation of the inbound change fails. When I view the reasons for the failure I see there are five headings in the **Component Deployment Results** table: *API Name*, *Type*, *Line*, *Column*, *Problem*.

The line and column headings give me some hope there could be some logs available that will let me decipher the somewhat cryptic *Problem* statement (this is a dashboard issue) which says:

> The values of chartSummary and/or groupingColumn are not compatible
>   with the autoselectColumnsFromReport mode for Metric

Is there a log that I can look at?
If not, how would I determine which particular element of the dashboard is causing me problems here?

Thanks

Comment: While I can't help you on where to look to solve your issue, I believe the line & column are mostly to reference apex/visualforce related errors, referencing which parts of test have failed.

Comment: @Sdry - Thanks for your comment. I should have noted in my original question that I haven't actually written an Apex code or VisualForce pages for this deployment, although this could have created an error in existing code, I suppose.

Comment: So what was the issue and what was the fix @Joe ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The line and column in this particular case (a dashboard) refers to the `metadata` xml file for the dashboard that can be accessed through the Force.com IDE.

If the error had been for a trigger or some other Apex code, the line and column would obviously refer directly to the line and column of the Apex code.

Comment: Have you ever used the line and column to diagnose a deployment problem with a dashboard or other metadata component? How useful is it?